# Restoration of functional dependencies in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, functional-dependencies

I have such table (http://img836.imageshack.us/img836/1418/47709342.png). 
And I need to find the dependence of RT(RW, WT, PT). I.e. i must receive the function of three variables. How can i do this with MATLAB or some another program?

Comment: Your first action should be to look at the data (plot it) and decide what kind of function is most likely to fit it. Then you need to estimate the parameters of this function, for which the methods are multitudinous. If you want help with the first step I suggest you plot it and post a picture of that. It is unlikely that someone will type your data in manually and plot it themselves.

Comment: Here is a simple solution for this problem: [http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/data_analysis/f1-8450.html#f1-7351](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/data_analysis/f1-8450.html#f1-7351)